# Why is there a comment in my inbox that doesn't exist?

Tags: support, global-inbox, stack-exchange-button

[image]

Neither I nor anyone else can see the top comment, which is apparently placed against [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6356063/strange-hibernate-createsqlquery-returns-a-charcharacter-but-string).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Bugs should be posted right here, so that's fine.

And I suspect that the comment in your inbox was deleted after it reached your inbox - in this case your inbox is not updated.

Comment: yes it might be possible that commenter has deleted his own

Comment: @Ravi this is correct, or it could have been removed by a ♦ or by users flagging it. But I suspect it *was* probably the user as the snippet we can see doesn't seem that it would warrant this type of attention.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot see the comment because it has been deleted, which would happen because:

- the user who wrote the comment deleted it
- the comment has been flagged by the enough users, and it has been automatically deleted
- a moderator deleted the comment for moderation reasons