# Inbox showed comment that is not present

Tags: bug, comments, global-inbox

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why is there a comment in my inbox that doesn't exist?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/95230/why-is-there-a-comment-in-my-inbox-that-doesnt-exist)

I received an Inbox notification with the comment:

> This is not a helpful response. You have no idea

But when I click the Question link, no comment contains that text. Also, no comment has been edited. Where did this come from? Or did someone post a comment with the @ notation, then delete it and post a more appropriate comment (should the Inbox notification then be deleted, if the comment is deleted?)?

Comment: I hadn't seen this other question in my search, should I delete this question, or mark it an answered (only answer so far alludes to similar points) or answer it myself with that reference?.

Comment: CrackerJack9, I suspect that this question will be closed shortly, you do not need to delete it.  In fact, even though it is a duplicate, it may still have value for search purposes.

Comment: Sounds good, thanks for your feedback!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Almost certainly the comment was deleted, either by the OP or a moderator. It sounds like the type of comment I would delete. The inbox is a different database, so it still had record of the comment, but perhaps this could be solved by the developers?

Comment: It bothers me when a response to my comment is shown in my inbox and the question is deleted before I can view it.  I'm nowhere near the 10k required to go find it and it's happened more than once.  That said, it sounds like this [should've been resolved?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/65567/deleted-comments-persist-in-the-global-inbox/65792#65792).

Comment: @M.Tibbits: Doesn't matter what your reputation is. 10k users can't see deleted comments anyway. That's a diamond-moderator only privilege.

Comment: Oh I see.  Thanks.  I had thought otherwise.

Comment: @TheEstablishment: I don't think even Diamond mods can see deleted comments... But they can see, as can 10K users, comments deleted because they were attached to deleted questions/answers...