# Inbox contains a message, but I can't find it

Tags: support, answers, global-inbox

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why is there a comment in my inbox that doesn't exist?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/95230/why-is-there-a-comment-in-my-inbox-that-doesnt-exist)

I posted this question a while ago. Two comments were added (one by be). A while later, I see the following in my inbox:

```
"answer on Colored jcombobox with colored items and focus"
"please split Editor and Renderer, and add to"
```

But I can not see that text (the second line) on the page with my question.

Is something wrong?

Can anyone else see this?

Answer (score 0):

The user [mkorbel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/714968/mkorbel) posted answer and deleted it shortly after. Here is his answer: (click for full view)

[image: answer screenshot]

He didn't leave any comment why he deleted the post, you can post comment on one of his older questions (so only he will see this) asking about it.