# Is it required to make edits that reviewers suggest in comments?

Tags: discussion, comments, accepted-answer

About 18 months back I posted [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6107676/520044) which the OP was happy with, as he accepted it. This is on a topic which I was working on at the time, but haven't touched in more than a year.

Since yesterday I'm going back and forth in comments with somebody who is, amongst other things, asking me to answer the question.

I feel I did, just not *in code*. In my mind this was more of a conceptual question, and the concept of what to change is contained in my answer.

To me this feels like nitpicking ... anyhow, I don't really have time for this, so I'm happy to have this answer deleted, if that's what stops this going on any further.

**EDIT**

BTW, I left a comment for him to continue this here at meta, with a link to this post.

His response was a comment on that answer, which is not visible there. But in my inbox notification I see an excerpt of it, basically saying he's not going to come here and discuss it.

I'm not sure if this is a comment he made and then deleted, or if he can post "publicly invisible" comments at 61k rep.

Comment: as far as I can tell, _amongst other things_ there was a suggestion to fix dead link in your answer - which I think is anything but nitpicking

Comment: `I'm not sure if this is a comment he made and then deleted, or if he can post "publicly invisible" comments at 61k rep.` The first one, most likely. :)

Comment: If you make a comment and then immediately delete it, it appears only in the inbox of anyone who would be notified by it (eg poster / `@`-pinged person)

Comment: @gnat I fixed that, as you can see in my answer to that first comment of his, I didn't have any problem with it until then. After that it went downhill ... although some of the comments the content of which I didn't really appreciate aren't there anymore (probably enough others didn't either).

Comment: @AkashM Thanks, I didn't know that. I somehow expected the inbox to be cleared of it too.

Comment: [This is the meta q](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/95230/why-is-there-a-comment-in-my-inbox-that-doesnt-exist)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The user was reacting to the fact that your answer was supported with links that no longer worked. We don't retain answers that depend entirely on external sources for relevance and context. When links break, so do the answers.

But that wasn't the case here, the meat of your answer is actually in the second paragraph and you managed to fix the links. The answer might not be as *good* without support from the links if they break again, but it could still stand on its own, and that's all we ask. If you feel anything could be added to it then of course feel free to do so.

I see no reason to remove the answer.

As for the comment, The user just left it and deleted it, probably after having second thoughts about writing it for whatever reason. What you saw was just an artifact of the newer instant notification system - no supernatural powers at work, I promise :)

The user was just doing their best to help maintain the site by reviewing answers .. rather intensely .. but helping nonetheless.

Answer (score 16):

You answered the question posted by the OP, whom marked your answer as helpful. You received upvotes. You should certainly not delete the answer.

Comments are just comments, not demands. Just ignore them if you don't have time for a longer answer. And you can always update the answer later, when you *do* have time.