# What happens to comments when an answer is deleted?

Tags: support, comments, answers

I'm sorry if this has been answered already but I've looked at some of the related questions and answers, but couldn't find the answer I was looking for.

Consider this scenario:

1. I post an answer to a question
2. The OP notifies me in a comment (on my answer) that the answer isn't valid for some reason
3. I post a follow up comment @OP (on my answer)
4. I then delete my answer as it was incorrect

My question is this:
Will the OP be notified of my last comment and will the OP be able to read it even though the answer it was attached to has been deleted?

Comment: Something like described here http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/95230/why-is-there-a-comment-in-my-inbox-that-doesnt-exist will happen

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They'll get a notification, but that notification will go away as soon as you delete the post.

If they had a page open when you posted they comment, and don't reload the page after the post is deleted, they'll still see the notification, but it will go away when the page is reloaded.

They will only be able to read the comment if they happen to follow the notification before it disappears, and if they have over 10k reputation (or happen to load the page before you delete the post).